# How do we characterise "swapping" in the unique isomorphism between $X \sqcup Y$ and $Y \sqcup X$?

Tags: category-theory

Let ${C}$ be category with coproducts. Then for any two objects $X$ and $Y$, we have $X \sqcup Y$ which is unique upto a unique isomorphism.
In a cocartesian monoidal category, the coproduct plays the role of the monoidal product (with Axiom of Choice) and we make it a symmetric monoidal category by considering the unique isomorphism $h \colon X \sqcup Y \rightarrow Y \sqcup X$ satisfying the Universal property.

My question is that in general how we distinguish between the object $Y \sqcup X$ and any other coproduct $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$? In concrete categories like Set, Cat etc, I can understand the isomorphism $h \colon X \sqcup Y \rightarrow Y \sqcup X$ (as a swapping), but how do we characterise such "swapping" in general to distinguish between $Y \sqcup X$ and $Z$?

Or, is it that any choice of coproduct $Z$ with the unique isomorphism $h_Z \colon X \sqcup Y \rightarrow Z$ can be thought as $Y \sqcup X$ and **it is just a choice we make while defining a cocartesian monoidal category?** Personally, I feel this is the case!

Answer (score 1):

the coproduct of two objects $X$ and $Y$ is defined up to a unique isomorphism. This means that, given any two objects $X$ and $Y$, there exists a coproduct $X ⊔ Y$, and any other coproduct $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$ is isomorphic to $X ⊔ Y$. However, the question at hand revolves around the distinction between $Y ⊔ X$ and any arbitrary coproduct $Z$ within a general categorical framework.

To delve into this, let's focus on the swapping isomorphism $h: X ⊔ Y → Y ⊔ X.$

**1**) In a category with coproducts, consider the inclusion morphisms $i_1: X \to X \sqcup Y$ and $i_2: Y \to X \sqcup Y$.
The universal property of the coproduct guarantees a unique morphism $h: X \sqcup Y \to Y \sqcup X$ such that $h \circ i_1 = i_2$ and $h \circ i_2 = i_1$.

**2)** Let $h_1: X \sqcup Y \to Y \sqcup X$ and $h_2: X \sqcup Y \to Y \sqcup X$ be two swapping isomorphisms.
The universal property provides unique morphisms $h_1': Y \sqcup X \to X \sqcup Y$ and $h_2': Y \sqcup X \to X \sqcup Y$ such that $h_1' \circ h_1 = \text{id}$ and $h_2' \circ h_2 = \text{id}$.
The equations are: $h_1' \circ h_1 = \text{id}$ and $h_2' \circ h_2 = \text{id}$.
The composition $h_2' \circ h_1'$ implies $h_1' = h_2'$, establishing the uniqueness of the swapping isomorphism.

**3)** Consider another coproduct $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$, with inclusion morphisms $i_X: X \to Z$ and $i_Y: Y \to Z$.
Utilizing the swapping isomorphism $h: Y \sqcup X \to X \sqcup Y$, form the composition $g = h \circ (i_Y \sqcup i_X): Z \to X \sqcup Y$.
The equation is: $g = h \circ (i_Y \sqcup i_X)$.
This composition yields a unique isomorphism between $Z$ and $Y \sqcup X$, demonstrating that any coproduct $Z$ of $X$ and $Y$ is isomorphic to $Y \sqcup X$ via the swapping isomorphism.

Comment: But, how are you characterising the swapping isomorphism?  I think your conclusion will hold for **any two choices of coproducts with their respective unique isomorphisms to the particular choice $X \sqcup Y$**.

Comment: Please, see my last portion of the question. I added later. I feel that is the case here.

Comment: @mathematicsstudent ohh... sorry for not seeing that .     the swapping isomorphism $h:Y⊔X→X⊔Y$ is unique up to isomorphism, and it allows us to distinguish between any coproduct $Z of X$ and $Y $and the coproduct $Y⊔X$. By defining a unique isomorphism $g:Z→Y⊔X$ using the swapping isomorphism h, we can show that any coproduct $Z$ is isomorphic to $Y⊔X$ , sorry for any other inconveniences hope this helps